# Why Vue.js doesn't trigger reactivity when Component Props are changed in a helper function, outside of the Component scope(in a different file)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I prefer to move functionality outside Components when the Component code becomes to crowded. So, this is a problem with which I have confronted several times when I have passed Component Props as arguments to functions that were outside of the Component scope, hosted in a different file as helper functions or as class methods. The mistake was fed also by the personal idea that I should use imutable objects everywere for better performance.

```
// the component file hosted in "MyComponent.vue"
<template>
  <button @click="update">Please, update!</button>
</template>

<script>
import {
  updatePrimitiveFn,
  updateLiteralObjectFn,
  updateArrayFn,
} from "../helpers.js";

export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      primitiveToBeUpdated: false,
      arrayToBeUpdated: [],
      literalObjectToBeUpdated: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      updatePrimitiveFn(this.primitiveToBeUpdated);
      updatedLiteralObjectFn(this.literalObjectToBeUpdated);
      updateArrayFn(this.arrayToBeUpdated);
      console.log("primitiveToBeUpdated", this.primitiveToBeUpdated);
      console.log("literalObjectToBeUpdated", this.literalObjectToBeUpdated);
      console.log("arrayToBeUpdated", this.arrayToBeUpdated);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
// the helpers functions hosted in "helpers.js"

export function updatePrimitiveFn(primitiveParameter) {
  primitiveParameter = true; // it will not trigger reactivity, the argument it's a primitive and for primitives JavaScript copies the argument value to the formal parameter. For arguments that are objects, JavaScript copies the pointers of these objects to the formal parameter, keeping the link between component props and formal parameters. Pointers stores the memory address where some data lives.
}
export function updateLiteralObjectFn(literalObjectParameter) {
  literalObjectParameter = { value: true }; // it will not trigger reactivity, it replaces the pointer of the received argument with a fresh new one. 
}

export function updateArrayFn(arrayToBeUpdated) {
  arrayToBeUpdated = [true]; // it will not trigger reactivity, it replaces the pointer of the received argument with a fresh new one.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to pass only objects, as arguments, to the external functions and mutate them as follows:

```
// the helpers functions hosted in "helpers.js"

export function updatePrimitiveFn(primitiveParameter) {
  primitiveParameter = true; // it will not trigger reactivity, the argument it's a primitive and for primitives JavaScript copies the argument value to the formal parameter. For arguments that are objects, JavaScript copies the pointers of these objects to the formal parameter, keeping the link between component props and formal parameters. Pointers stores the memory address where some data lives.
}
export function updateLiteralObjectFn(literalObjectParameter) {
  literalObjectParameter.value = true; // mutation keeps pointing same object in memory
}
export function updateArrayFn(arrayToBeUpdated) {
  arrayToBeUpdated.push(true); mutation keeps pointing same object in memory
}
```

Check live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-volhard-mf6x0?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue:0-179

For more information can be studied the subject "Pass by Value vs. Pass by Reference".